# lang.NumberFormatException in android

Tags: java, android, exception

I have the following code which does nothing but reading some values from a DB in a background thread and using the values I draw a Line chart using a jar.For the line chart I use for value for each array and the problem is that the third that I pass to the constructor that draws the LineChart is float....

---

```
float[] viteza;

String[] time;

int contor=0;
```

---

```
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    init_task = new InitTask();

    init_task.execute(db);

}

public class InitTask extends AsyncTask<DBAdapter,String, Void> {

    String TABLE_3;

    protected Void doInBackground(DBAdapter... db) {
        try {
            db[0].createDatabase();
            db[0].openDataBase();
            Cursor c = db[0].getCursor3(db[0].TABLE_3, user_id);

            String[] array=new String[2];
            viteza = new float[c.getCount()];
            time = new String[c.getCount()];

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                do {


                    publishProgress(c.getString(3),c.getString(4));
                    Thread.sleep(500);


                } while (c.moveToNext());

            }
            c.close();
            db[0].close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Eroare", "doInBackground", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String...values) {

        Aitem items[] = new Aitem[1];

        viteza[contor]=Float.valueOf(values[0]);
        time[contor]=values[1];
        if(contor>3)
        {
        items[0]=new Aitem(Color.RED, "Evolution",viteza);
        lv.setTitle("Evolutia vitezei");

        lv.setAxisValueX(time);

        setContentView(lv);
        }
        contor++;
    }

}



}
```

I get error at this line:

```
viteza[contor]=Float.valueOf(values[0]);


java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
   at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFltImpl(Native Method)
 at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:321)
```

Has anyone any clue what is gooing wrong???

EDIT:

In my humble opinion values[0]=c.getString(3)  and values[1]=c.getString(4) so ....are Strings...aren't they?

Comment: You left out the most important part: what's the value of `values[0]`?

Comment: =)))....when I posted this I said I have to put all the  variables I use...so THEY can fgure out what I'm doing wrong and yet...I'll edit my question;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure just by looking at this, but I can tell you, this is where Log.v is extremely handy. Put a Log.v(TAG,"\""+values[]+"\""), and you'll see exactly what's getting to that function. If it's anything other than a pure number, that'd be what's causing the exception to occur.

Comment: (601): "214.721"

(601): "0"
I assume that there are numbers...only this I got displayed after that FC came;)))

Comment: @george - Do you mean that `values[0]` contains exactly `214.721`? It it the same as doing `values[0] = "214.721";`?

Comment: values[0] in my DB is 214.721099853516  but in my logcat...using Log.v()....it displays "214.721"....but I assume that " "...comes from "+values[]+"

Comment: @george - You could try `Log.v(TAG,values[0]);`, so it will be without `"`'s.

Comment: I TRIED....THERE ARE CORRECT NUMBERS DISPLAYED.....SOMEWHERE ELSE IS THE PROBELM.....

Comment: @george: It seems like it should be working. The parenthesis are to help make sure there isn't a null or space messing things up, which seems to be good. Hmmmm... Did you put this before the floating point conversion statement?

Comment: @george: Did the logging help discover that?

Comment: Yes....it did....but now I have another issue...in which the logging can't help:|

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the first element isn't a proper string containing a float.

So obviously the content of c.getString(3) must be wrong. Check that this is a string, and that this string contains strictly a float. Check for invalid characters, spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try catch` block where you are parsing string into int

```
try{
// todo

}

catch( NumberFormatException ex ) {

}
```